# Backbone JSON request troubles from PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json, backbone.js

My first post on stackoverflow.
I am developing a system that incorporates a client side javascript and backbone.js and highcharts.js to display real-time data from my renewable energy system at home.

It uses a small micro-controller called an Arduino to handle the sensor data at a low level.
The controller has its own ethernet hardware and I have it setup as a small server.

In my client-side program I use Backbone as the MVC and the model URL's point to the Arduino's IP to request a json data packet. Works well.

What I am now doing is to move that URL pointer to my hosted site where I have a small php file to pull the data out of an SQL table and present that in same json format.

From my browser when I request the json data packet from the Arduino controller it looks like this;

```
<head></head><body><pre>{"vT_pv":234.00,"iT_pv":5.90,"iS_pv":0.00,"vB_pv":27.51}</pre></body>
```

And when I point the browser to my hosted site where I call the php, it looks like this;

```
<head></head><body><pre>{"vT_pv":230.70,"iT_pv":4.90,"iS_pv":0.00,"vB_pv":27.56}</pre></body>
```

Edit: have included full headers as requested by Alex

Both appear the same and yet in my client-side javascript only the first one actually works in that the data is successfully put into the model and then viewable on the screen.

One difference between the two, when I inspect the page is that my Arduino returns as HTTP/1.0 where as the returned json data from my hosted site is HTTP/1.1

Would this be enough to cause such a problem?

The following is the backbone model for that json;

```
PollerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
//  url:'//xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/poller.json',    // this one works
    url: 'http://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.host_site/sql_get_live.php',    // this one does not

    startUpdate: function() {
        var that = this;
        startUpdate(that);
        function  startUpdate(isThis) {
            that.fetch({async:false});
            pollerUpdateInterval = setTimeout(function(){startUpdate(that);}, 5000);
        };
    },
});
```

As you can see, once the startUpate function is called it is forever called every 5 seconds, which is what I want.

When I use the first URL which points to the micro-controller it works like a charm.
When I use the second URL, I can see that it goes out to make the request and that it gets a reply, but it appears to do nothing with the data, it doesn't put into the model.

So on my client side app, the first URL I see data on the rendered view, but not with the second URL.

The following is the php file Ihave on the host site;

```
<?php

//  The JSON standard MIME header.
//  header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

    $con = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password');
    if (!$con) {
        die('mysql connect error: ' .mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("DataBase", $con);

    $sql_Live = "SELECT * FROM live";
    $mysql_record = mysql_query($sql_Live,$con);

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_record);
    $jsonData = '{"vT_pv":' . $row['vT_pv'] . ',"iT_pv":' . "4.90" . ',"iS_pv":' . $row['iS_pv'] . ',"vB_pv":' . $row['vB_pv'] . '}';
    echo "<pre >";
    echo $jsonData;
    echo "</pre>";
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The header that is commented out makes no difference to the format or any result.
I have tried using the json encode function in various ways, all without success.
in fact using the json encode produces what I think is non-json format, so maybe the format above how I use is not formatted correctly? Yet it works for the first URL?

I have searched and am feeling a bit stuck here, so I thought it was time for me to ask.

Paul

Comment: Can you update your question with the full http headers for both, I've almost no doubt this is an issue with the headers.

Comment: Sorry Alex, I have only just noticed your request 2 hours later. Do you mean the headers for each of the browser requests above? I can do that, though I looked carefully at the URl that worked and I made the php produce the same, hence the 'pre' tags.

Comment: yep, in chrome go:view>developer>developer tools>network tab> then reload and select the file from the left panel, then look at the 'headers tab' it will give you every http header sent or recieved in full detail then u can work out the differences between the 2 results

Comment: Man you're good Alex. The first URL has content-type application/json, and you guessed, the second has plain jane text/html. So there is my problem then I guess. Let me see how I fix that. Thank you very much Alex. I hope that will fix the problem. Paul

Comment: :-) seen it before....it may be apache overriding your PHP header(); if so change the content type in an .htaccess file or delete the content-type text/html attribution for .php files in httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks Alex, I should use Chrome a bit more than I do FF. This might be the time. Totally cool. How does one give credit, you haven't come in under an answer?

Comment: you can do the same thing via the 'firebug' add-on/extension for firefox, but chrome and safari have this built in.. glad I could help and welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've almost no doubt this is an issue with the headers.

in chrome go:view>developer>developer tools>network tab> then reload and select the file from the left panel, then look at the 'headers tab' it will give you every http header sent or recieved in full detail then u can work out the differences between the 2 results.

your php `header("content-type"...)` should work but if not it may be apache overriding your PHP header(); if so change the content type in an `.htaccess` file or delete the `content-type text/html` attribution for .php files in httpd.conf.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP, you're doing this:

```
echo "<pre >";
echo $jsonData;
echo "</pre>";
```

`$jsonData` looks like valid JSON but `<pre>$jsonData</pre>` won't be JSON, that will be JSON wrapped in some HTML. You should be able to simply `echo $jsonData;` without the `<pre>` wrapper and get sensible results in the JavaScript; I'd include the `Content-Type: application/json` header as well.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, though I have tried doing as you have suggested, but again, without any success. Yes, the 'pre' just puts it as plain text. When I include the header for Content-type, again, there is no difference. Paul Edit: I shall remove the 'pre'

Comment: What happens if you add an `error` callback to the `fetch` call?

Comment: I am wonderif my syntax for the second URL is correct, where I use 'http://yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.myhostsitename/myphp.php'?  It works in the browser, but maybe there is a different format I need to use here?  Paul

Comment: Usually you use a host-less URL to avoid cross-host issues. Is your PHP script getting called?

Comment: What I have ben able to do from the browser is to drop the IP and just use the web-site name, so for example just have 'http;//mysite.com/directory/myphp.php. Though still not working in backbone if I use this as the URL. When I call the php from my server here, it works, albeit with a dummy json data as I don't have sql setup. So, does this mean it's a cross domain issue? If so, then why does the client side work for getting json data directly from my little Arduino which is on a different IP than the host site that servs up the page?

Comment: An error callback to the fetch call, ok I will look into putting something there. I placed a console.log directly after the fetch to see what was happing in the object, empty as for the second URL